Problemas con la gestión de la lista de archivos en un modal
Tengo un modal al cual puedo subir archivos manualmente mediante un botón o mediante Drag and Drop, tengo un bug independientemente de como suba el archivo:
El bug ocurre al momento de tratar con el listado de documentos, al añadir uno o varios documentos que no estén previamente sale el botón de start que inicia la subida del archivo y delete que elimina el archivo del listado y también aparecen los botones de Subir todo y Borrar todo. Los fallos son que al borrar 2 documentos del listado ya sea duplicado o no desaparecen los botones de subir todo y borrar todo y a los documentos originales les aparece la barra de progreso que solo debería de aparecer cuando se sube el documento.
Antes de borrar algun archivo:

Despues de borrar dos archivos:

Este es mi código:
Upload-modal.php
<?php
// Ordenar el array $uploadFolders alfabéticamente por el campo 'path'
usort($uploadFolders, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['path'], $b['path']);
});
?>
<form class="form" action="none" id="kt_modal_upload_form">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="fw-bold"><?= lang('General.upload') ?></h2>
        <div Onclick="location.reload();" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-active-icon-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-1">
                <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect opacity="0.5" x="6" y="17.3137" width="16" height="2" rx="1" transform="rotate(-45 6 17.3137)" fill="currentColor" />
                    <rect x="7.41422" y="6" width="16" height="2" rx="1" transform="rotate(45 7.41422 6)" fill="currentColor" />
                </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body pt-10 pb-15 px-lg-17">
        <form class="form" action="<?= site_url('upload_files') ?>" method="post" id="uploadForm">
            <div class="col-xxl-12">
                <div class="row g-8 mb-8">
                    <div class="col-xxl-8">
                        <label class="fs-6 form-label fw-bold text-dark"><?= lang('General.folders') ?></label>
                        <select onChange="ChangeFolder()" class="form-select form-select-solid" id="uploadFolder" name="uploadFolder">
                            <option value=""><?= lang('General.selectUpload') ?></option>
                            <?php foreach ($uploadFolders as $folder) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $folder['path'] . (100000 + $folder['tag']) .  '" ';
                                echo ' >' . $folder['path'] . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <!-- Mensaje de error -->
                        <div id="folder-error" style="display: none; color: red; margin-top: 5px;">
                            <?= lang('General.selectFolderFirst') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $grupotags = "";
                foreach ($tags as $row) :
                    if ($row['group'] !== $grupotags && $grupotags !== "") :
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php
                    endif;
                    if ($row['group'] !== $grupotags) :
                        $grupotags = $row['group'];
        ?>
            <div class="collapse col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="collapseMetadata<?php echo (100000 + $row['group']); ?>">
            <?php
                    endif;
                    if ($row["value"] == 1) :
            ?>
                <div class="form-group row mb-3">
                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12 col-form-label text-dark"><?php echo str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-solid" type="text" name="<?php echo 'M_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?>" id="<?php echo 'M_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                    else :
                        if ($row["selectable"] == 1) :
                ?>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12">
                            <label class="form-check-label text-dark" for="<?php echo 'M_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?>"><?php echo str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'M_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?>" id="<?php echo 'M_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?>" value="onoff" unchecked />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        else :
                            if ($row["list"] !== null) :
                    ?>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-3">
                            <label class="col-form-label text-right col-lg-5 col-sm-12 text-dark"><?php echo str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                                <select class="form-select form-select-solid" style="width:auto;" name="<?php echo 'M_' . str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"]); ?>[]" id="<?php echo 'M_SELECCION_EXPEDIENTE'; ?>">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $list = explode(";", $row["list"]);
                                    foreach ($list as $option) {
                                        echo '<option value="' . $option . '">' . $option . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <?php
                            endif;
                        endif;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
        ?>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label text-lg-right"><?= lang('General.upload') ?></label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="dropzone dropzone-queue mb-2" id="kt_dropzonejs_example_2">
                    <div class="dropzone-panel mb-lg-0 mb-2">
                        <a class="dropzone-select btn btn-sm btn-primary me-2 disabled" id="attachFiles" name="attachFiles"><?= lang('General.upload') ?></a>
                        <a class="dropzone-upload btn btn-sm btn-light-primary me-2"><?= lang('General.uploadAll') ?></a>
                        <a class="dropzone-remove-all btn btn-sm btn-light-primary"><?= lang('General.removeAll') ?></a>
                        <button onclick="restoreUpload()" ; class="btn btn-primary" hidden><?php echo 'Restaurar';  ?></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropzone-items wm-200px">
                        <div class="dropzone-item" style="display:none">
                            <div class="dropzone-file">
                                <div class="dropzone-filename" title="some_image_file_name.jpg">
                                    <span data-dz-name>example.jpg</span>
                                    <strong>(<span data-dz-size>340kb</span>)</strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropzone-error" data-dz-errormessage></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropzone-progress">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropzone-toolbar">
                                <span class="dropzone-start"><i class="bi bi-play-fill fs-3"></i></span>
                                <span class="dropzone-cancel" data-dz-remove style="display: none;"><i class="bi bi-x fs-3"></i></span>
                                <span class="dropzone-delete" data-dz-remove><i class="bi bi-x fs-1"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Mensaje de "Suelte sus archivos aquí" -->
                    <div id="dropzone-message" style="display: none; text-align: center; padding: 20px; border: 2px dashed #007bff; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0; color: #007bff;"><?= lang('General.dropFilesHere') ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="form-text text-muted"><?= lang('General.maxFileSize') ?>:100MB</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

Script en Home.php
<!-- DROPZONE SUBMIT-->
<script>        
    // set the dropzone container id
    const id = "#kt_dropzonejs_example_2";
    const dropzone = document.querySelector(id);

    // set the preview element template
    var previewNode = dropzone.querySelector(".dropzone-item");
    previewNode.id = "";
    var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
    previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

    // Set to keep track of added files and duplicate files
    var addedFiles = new Set();
    var duplicateFiles = new Set();

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(id, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
        url: '<?= site_url('upload_files') ?>', // Set the url for your upload script location
        parallelUploads: 20,
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        maxFilesize: 100, // Max filesize in MB
        autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
        previewsContainer: id + " .dropzone-items", // Define the container to display the previews
        clickable: id + " .dropzone-select", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
        sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
            // Append `uploadFolder` field value to the form data
            formData.append("uploadFolder", document.querySelector('[name="uploadFolder"]').value);
            <?php
            foreach ($tags as $row) {
                if ($row["selectable"] == '1') {
                    echo ' formData.append("' . (str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"])) . '", document.querySelector(' . "'" . '[name="M_' . (str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"])) . '"]' . "').checked);\n";
                } else {
                    if ($row["value"] == '1') {
                        echo ' formData.append("' . (str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"])) . '", document.querySelector(' . "'" . '[name="M_' . (str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"])) . '"]' . "').value);\n";
                    } else {
                        echo ' formData.append("' . (str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"])) . '", document.querySelector(' . "'" . '[name="M_' . (str_replace(" ", "_", $row["name"])) . '[]"]' . "').value);\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
        },
        accept: function(file, done) {
            // Check if the file has already been added
            if (addedFiles.has(file.name)) {
                duplicateFiles.add(file.name);
                done("<?= lang('General.fileAlredyAdded') ?>");
            } else {
                // Add the file to the set of added files
                addedFiles.add(file.name);
                done();
            }
        }
    });

    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        // Check if a folder is selected
        const folderSelect = document.querySelector('[name="uploadFolder"]');
        const folderError = document.getElementById('folder-error');
        if (!folderSelect.value) {
            myDropzone.removeFile(file);
            folderError.style.display = 'block';
            return;
        } else {
            folderError.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Hookup the start button
        const startButton = file.previewElement.querySelector(".dropzone-start");
        if (startButton) {
            startButton.style.display = "inline-block";
            startButton.onclick = function() {
                myDropzone.enqueueFile(file);
            };
        }

        // Add click event to log file name
        const fileNameElement = file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-name]");
        if (fileNameElement) {
            fileNameElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("File name clicked:", file.name);
            });
        }

        const dropzoneItems = dropzone.querySelectorAll('.dropzone-item');
        dropzoneItems.forEach(dropzoneItem => {
            dropzoneItem.style.display = '';
        });
        dropzone.querySelector('.dropzone-upload').style.display = "inline-block";
        dropzone.querySelector('.dropzone-remove-all').style.display = "inline-block";
    });

    // Update the total progress bar
    myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
        const progressBars = dropzone.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
        progressBars.forEach(progressBar => {
            progressBar.style.width = progress + "%";
        });
    });

    myDropzone.on("sending", function(file) {
        // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
        const progressBars = dropzone.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
        progressBars.forEach(progressBar => {
            progressBar.style.opacity = "1";
        });
        // And disable the start button
        const startButton = file.previewElement.querySelector(".dropzone-start");
        if (startButton) {
            startButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });

    // Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
    myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
        const progressBars = dropzone.querySelectorAll('.dz-complete');

        setTimeout(function() {
            progressBars.forEach(progressBar => {
                progressBar.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.opacity = "0";
                progressBar.querySelector('.progress').style.opacity = "0";
                const startButton = progressBar.querySelector(".dropzone-start");
                if (startButton) {
                    startButton.style.opacity = "0";
                }
            });
        }, 300);
    });

    // Setup the buttons for all transfers
    dropzone.querySelector(".dropzone-upload").addEventListener('click', function() {
        myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
    });

    // Setup the button for remove all files
    dropzone.querySelector(".dropzone-remove-all").addEventListener('click', function() {
        dropzone.querySelector('.dropzone-upload').style.display = "none";
        dropzone.querySelector('.dropzone-remove-all').style.display = "none";
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
        addedFiles.clear(); // Clear the set of added files
        duplicateFiles.clear(); // Clear the set of duplicate files
    });

    // On all files completed upload
    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
        const uploadIcons = dropzone.querySelectorAll('.dropzone-upload');
        uploadIcons.forEach(uploadIcon => {
            uploadIcon.style.display = "none";
        });
    });

    // On all files removed
    myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {
        // Remove the file from the set of added files or duplicate files
        if (duplicateFiles.has(file.name)) {
            duplicateFiles.delete(file.name);
        } else {
            addedFiles.delete(file.name);
        }

        // Ensure progress bar is hidden for remaining files
        const progressBars = dropzone.querySelectorAll('.dz-complete');
        progressBars.forEach(progressBar => {
            progressBar.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.opacity = "0";
            progressBar.querySelector('.progress').style.opacity = "0";
        });

        // Remove the file from Dropzone's internal files array
        myDropzone.files = myDropzone.files.filter(f => f.name !== file.name);

        if (myDropzone.files.length < 1) {
            dropzone.querySelector('.dropzone-upload').style.display = "none";
            dropzone.querySelector('.dropzone-remove-all').style.display = "none";
        }
    });

    // Variables para controlar el estado del mensaje
    let dragCounter = 0;
    const dropzoneMessage = document.getElementById('dropzone-message');

    // Mostrar mensaje de "Suelte sus archivos aquí" cuando se arrastran archivos sobre la zona de Dropzone
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragenter', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dragCounter++;
        dropzoneMessage.style.display = 'block';
    });

    // Ocultar mensaje de "Suelte sus archivos aquí" cuando se sale de la zona de Dropzone
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragleave', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dragCounter--;
        if (dragCounter === 0) {
            dropzoneMessage.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    // Prevenir el comportamiento por defecto para evitar que el navegador abra el archivo
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Ocultar mensaje de "Suelte sus archivos aquí" cuando se sueltan archivos en la zona de Dropzone
    dropzone.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dragCounter = 0;
        dropzoneMessage.style.display = 'none';
    });

    // Ocultar el mensaje de error al seleccionar una carpeta
    const folderSelect = document.querySelector('[name="uploadFolder"]');
    folderSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const folderError = document.getElementById('folder-error');
        if (folderSelect.value) {
            folderError.style.display = 'none';
            addedFiles.clear(); // Clear the set of added files 
            duplicateFiles.clear(); // Clear the set of duplicate files
        }
    });
</script>

Muchisimas gracias a todos!

@masterguru no comprendo, la pregunta es sobre los dos bugs que tengo en mi modal, alomejor lo de subida manual y drag and drop es lo que confunde? porque el bug ocurre suba el archivo por drag and drop o manual

@HugoJiménez lo que dice, es que enfoques la pregunta a 1 problema, no a 2. Ya que si busco algun detalle o algo, me toparía con la descripcion de uno y no 2 al tratar de buscar una solución. Primero, edita esta pregunta y solo consulta sobre el problema con el listado y el eliminar. Luego de resolver eso, haz el 2do problema.

@Excorpion ah okey, lo hago ahora mismo, disculpad las molestias

No hay problema ;)
